# How to use java riak client without dependency issues

Tags: riak

I am trying to use the Java Riak Client an existing project that I am working on. I am using `riak-client-1.0.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

I keep on getting errors like this one:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect
```

And this one:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager
```

when I try to execute basic examples.

I would appreciate if somebody could point me to a straightforward way to include all of the necessary dependencies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1.0.6 Riak java client does not use Jackson 2.x which is what your first error is saying is missing or Apache's HTTP client 4.2.x which is what your second error says is missing. (You can determine that by the package structure in Jackson and the class in question in the Apache library).

Given that, it would seem your own code does and because you don't have those dependencies you're receiving those errors.

I would highly suggest using maven but in lieu of that you can download the jar-with-dependencies for the current version of the Riak client (1.1.0) which actually has had those packages upgraded to 2.1.2 and 4.2.2 respectively; it's available at: http://riak-java-client.s3.amazonaws.com/riak-client-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: Thanks, I was not able to find 1.1 with dependencies. As for using maven, are there any simple instructions as to how to include a maven project in my existing project? I am using ant to build. I have used maven before, but never tried integrating it into an existing project. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that re: not finding it. Github just axed their "downloads" feature which is where I used to put it. I need to update the README there with a link to its new home. As for mixing maven into an existing ant project ... that's probably nothing but tears but I've not ever tried it.

Comment: Well, I feel better about not being able to find the 1.1-with-dependencies jar, and about my fears of trying to mix maven with an ant project. And I now realize that you are a riak developer. +1 for validating the issues I was having AND for making an awesome datastore.